# Map inserstion failure: can not overwrite first element?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

```
static std::map <unsigned int, CPCSteps> bestKvariables;

inline void copyKBestVar(MaxMinVarMap& vMaxMinAll, size_t& K, std::vector<unsigned int>& temp)
{
    // copy top k variables and store in a vector.
    MaxMinVarMap::reverse_iterator iter1;
    size_t count;
    for (iter1 = vMaxMinAll.rbegin(), count = 0; iter1 != vMaxMinAll.rend()&& count <= K; ++iter1, ++count)
    {
        temp.push_back(iter1->second);
    }
}

void myAlgo::phase1(unsigned int& vTarget)
{

    CPCSteps KBestForT; // To store kbest variables for only target variable finally put in a global storage
    KBestForT.reserve(numVars);
    std::vector<unsigned int> tempKbest;
    tempKbest.reserve(numVars);
    .......
    .......
    copyKBestVar(mapMinAssoc, KBestSize, tempKbest); // Store k top variables as a k best for this CPC variable for each step
    KBestForT.push_back(tempKbest);
    .....
    .....
    bestKvariables.insert(make_pair(vTarget, KBestForT)); // Store k best in a Map
    .....
    ....
}
```

The Problem: Map "bestKvariables" is not overwriting the first element, but it keeps updating the rest of the elements. I tried to debug it but the problem i found is in insert command.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Another Question: whether i can reserve the size of a map(like vector.reserve(..)) in the beginning to avoid the insertion cost.

Sorry for providing insufficient information.

I means if there are four vTarget variables 1, 2, 3, 4. I do some statistical calculations for each variable. 
There are more than one iterations for these variables, i would like to store top k results of each variable in a map to use it next iteration.

I saw the first inserted variable(with key unsigned int "vTarget") is not updated on further iterations(it remains the value inserted on first iteration).
But the other variables (keys inserted after the first) are remains updated.

Comment: What do you mean by `not overwriting the first element, but it keeps updating the rest of the elements`? Maybe you can give an example or explain what you expect it to do.

Comment: question formatting... it helps

Comment: Just a guess, a map can only store one value per one unique key. Perhaps you need a multi_map, if two keys can be the same.

Comment: Means, it is not updating first inserted key, it keeps the previous value. But for the other keys it update on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map::insert` isn't supposed to update/overwrite *anything*, just **insert** not-yet-present elements. Use `operator[]` for updating, it also inserts elements when the specified key is not present yet.

Comment: Thanks, but key is there "vTarget", bestKvariables.insert(make_pair(vTarget, KBestForT));   unsigned int vTarget;

Comment: @user986789 ?? I don't know what you're trying to tell me with this comment, but what happens when you do `bestKvariables[vTarget]=KBestForT;`?

Answer (score 3):

> Another Question: whether i can reserve the size of a map(like vector.reserve(..)) in the beginning to avoid the insertion cost.

`std::map` **does not** have a `reserve()` function unlike `std::vector`.
Usually, the Standard library provides functions for containers that provide and ensure good performance or provide a means to achieve the same.

For a container like `std::vector` reallocation of its storage can be a very costly
operation. A simple call to `push_back()` can lead to every element in the `std::vector` to be copied to a newly allocated block of memory. A call to `reserve()` can avoid these unnecessary allocations and copy operations for `std::vector` and hence the same is provided for it.

`std::map` never needs to copy all of the existing/remaining elements simply because a new element was inserted or removed. Hence it does not provide any such function.

Though the Standard does not specify how a `std::map` should be implemented the behavior expected and the complexity desired ensures that most implementations implement it as a `tree`, unlike `std::vector` which needs elements to be allocated in contiguous memory locations.